# FreeSwitch, mod_conference flags and Lua

Tags: lua, freeswitch

Was hoping someone could help me with the syntax to set the vmute member flag from a lua script please?

The documentation for mod_conference says that the dialplan syntax for joining with a flag is:

[`confname+1234+flags{mute}`](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_conference)

My script works and connects the member fine, and works for the member flag 'ghost' / 'second-screen' etc, but it doesn't work for vmute:

`session:execute("conference", pin .."@cp+flags{vmute}");`

Is this the right syntax? The member joins the conference, but doesn't appear to be vmuted (esl events show 'see' = true).

I'd just like the user to connect without video. Is this possible?

Thanks